# How does HTML form function?

Tags: html, forms

How does HTML form function? and what I mean by that question is not what a form does (It sends the information of all the input elements to the server), but I mean "How does the form know what to do"? Isn't HTML just a mark-up language, which means that it's not for programming? Is there some code hidden somewhere?
I hope it was clear ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is processed by the browser, and the browser has programming which "makes the form work". All the form really does though (for most standard uses), is collect the user input and provide it as a POST request to the HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Its just part of the web browser to serialize the contents of the input fields and send that up to the server.